# py.exe で python2.7.17 が起動しません

Tags: python, api, python2, aibo-developer

Python 2.7.17 インストールにあたり、下記サイトを参考にさせていただきました。
https://www.python.jp/install/windows/install_py2.7.html
私の windows10 は 64bit版なので　Windows x86-64 MSI installer をダウンロードし、
c:\ にインストールしました。
そして上記サイトによれば、

> Pythonの拡張モジュールをインストールする際に、Cコンパイラが必要となる場合があります。

とのことなので、Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7　もダウンロードし、インストールしました。が、コマンドプロンプトで py.exe を打っても Python が起動しません。

---

C:\Users\kyoko>py.exe
'py.exe' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
C:\Users\kyoko>

---

https://www.python.jp/install/windows/py_launcher.html　によると、
py.exe は環境変数に設定しなくても構わないそうですが、何かが足りないのでしょうか？

https://www.javadrive.jp/python/install/index3.html
を参考に環境変数にc:\python27\を追加もしてみましたが、py.exe と打つと見つからない、
python.exe と打つとマイクロソフトストアで python3 を入手するかと窓が出ます。
毎度コマンドプロンプトで cd を使ってディレクトリ変更の必要があるのでしょうか？

c:\python27\ に python.exe は存在します。が、py.exe は見つかりません。
そして、スタートボタンから Python2.17 ボタンを押すと、コマンドプロンプトで
Python が起動するようです。

---

Python 2.7.17 (v2.7.17:c2f86d86e6, Oct 19 2019, 21:01:17) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
`>>> 1+1`
`2`
`>>>`

---

これで良いのか、何かがおかしいのか、判らず不安です。
ステップ毎に引っかかって申し訳ございませんが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: この記事を参考に。[Windows で複数バージョンの Python を使う](https://qiita.com/landwarrior/items/1b5e0f9af5316a025fe0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己回答です。
@ kunifさまのご教示に従って「Windows で複数バージョンの Python を使う」
https://qiita.com/landwarrior/items/1b5e0f9af5316a025fe0 を拝見しました。
私の Windows10 は 1903 で、確かに windows のフォルダに python.exe が入ってました。
なので取りあえず、私がインストールした Python2.17 をアンインストールし、
環境変数に追加した記述も削除してから、解説の多い Python3.7.5 をインストールしました。
Python3x であれば、「Add Python 3.x to PATH」のオプションがあるのも理由です。

> C:\Users\kyoko>py -V
>   Python 3.7.5
>
> C:\Users\kyoko>py.exe
>   Python 3.7.5 (tags/v3.7.5:5c02a39a0b, Oct 15 2019, 00:11:34) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>   `>>> 1+1`
>   2
>   `>>>`

お陰様で、ちゃんと出るようになりましたことをご報告させていただきます！