# py' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、 操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。 と表示される

Tags: python, windows

以下のように表示され、pyファイルを起動するバッチファイルなどを使うことができない。

```
py' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
```

Python自体は導入済みで、"python"コマンドは正常に機能することを確認済みです。
しかし"py"コマンドは認識されない。

数多のサイトではWindowsではPythonランチャーが使えるのでpyコマンドでpythonを起動することを推奨しているが、そもそもpyがコマンドとして認識されないためそれも不可能。

Comment: インストールするPythonをMicrosoft StoreやAnacondaなどPython.orgが配布しているインストーラーでは無い物を使っているか、Python.orgの物でもPythonランチャをインストールするチェックボックスを外してしまったのでは？ [Windows 環境のPython](https://www.python.jp/install/windows/index.html), [4. Windows で Python を使う](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/using/windows.html), [4.8. Windows の Python ランチャ](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/using/windows.html#launcher)

Comment: 過去の類似質問: [py.exe で python2.7.17 が起動しません](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/60787/3060)

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。